# What chat clients (that work on linux) support creating rooms?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need an alternative to Skype (I know of ekiga, but there is a problem in that anyone can join your ekiga room, and the rooms are not persistent as far as I know. If I am wrong, please let me know in a commment or answer, I'd be happy to be wrong (very happy)). IRC is fine too, but I would need instructions on how to do it (freenode?). Whatever you suggest needs to be:

1. free
2. persistent
3. crossplatform

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

By filling in the "Room" field with a non-existent room, you can create a chat room. I used Pidgin for this screenshot. To get to this dialog box I clicked "Buddies" then "Join Chat". Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew about doing this with the bonjour/avahi service before, but this is awesome now I know how to do it.

Comment: You're welcome! I just had to use that about 10 minutes before I found your question, so I'm glad I was able to explain it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

IRC will probably offer you the best featureset and platform support at the cost of having to find a good network, get involved with the services (register your nick, room, etc).

What about our very own chat here? http://chat.askubuntu.com It's not private and everybody will have to register but it's cross-platform and a doddle to setup once you're registered.

Comment: LOL!!! ;D Oli you're too funny :D

Comment: btw I think IRC is looking like a good plan B, thanks :)